# Best way to set a header to all tests using Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tdd, bdd, minitest, rails-api

.Hi. I have this API, and a custom header which is required to be passed in all requests to any controller. In Minitest, I should do `@request.headers['Custom-Header'] = 'Custom Value'` in every single test. Well, it happens I have many controllers, and this code is being repeated at the top `describe` block in each file.

I was trying to figure some way to make this DRYer. I even tried:

```
module Minitest::CustomHeaderSetup
  def before_setup
    super
    @request.headers['Custom-Header'] = 'Custom Value' if @request.present?
  end

  Minitest::Test.send(:include, self)
end
```

But `@request` doesn't exist at this moment. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solved!**

`Minitest::Test.send(:include, self)` applies that code to every single test file, not only controller tests. So, what should be actually done is:

```
module Minitest::CustomHeaderSetup
  def before_setup
    super
    @request.headers['Custom-Header'] = 'Custom Value'
  end
end
```

And to those controller test files we want to behave like this, we should add:

```
include Minitest::CustomHeaderSetup
```

**UPDATE**

This would automatically set the custom header to all your controller tests.

```
module Minitest::CustomHeaderSetup                                                       
  def before_setup
    super
    @request.headers['Custom-Header'] = 'Custom Value'
  end

  ActionController::TestCase.send(:include, self)
end
```

Comment: Hi, where should add these code, seems @request is nil?

Comment: `Minitest::CustomHeaderSetup` can go in a support test file as `test/support/custom_header_setup.rb`.